# With QVBoxLayout and a fixed height window adding one widget is in middle of window

Tags: pyqt, pyside6, qvboxlayout

When I set the height of my window and add one widget to the window it is vertically in the middle of the height.  I totally do not want this.  I have heard that setSpacing(0) on the layout can fix this.  It does not.  I to that to the layout of the window before adding the widget.  What am I missing?  I am very surprised and not at all happy that this seems to be default behavior.  It also makes a mess when I have multiple widgets and remove some as everything else adjusts to fill the vertical space.  Is there some setting I can turn off to remove this behavior?

Comment: You can add a stretch above or below the widget. That will push the widget to the bottom or the top respectively.

Comment: I found layout.insertStretch(-1) as last element did what I wanted nicely. Thanks!